# How to animate a progress bar in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, progress-bar

I am trying to animate Bootstrap progress bar, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I got the value of the width but `console.log(bar_width);` returns the width in `px` but not `%` as shown inline `style="width:90%`.

I recreated a bootply with the code: [BootStrap Progress Bar](http://www.bootply.com/KvaJrh46qK)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Skills Progress Bar -->
<section id="skills-pgr">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
            <span>HTML/CSS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
            <span>Photography</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:80%">
            <span>CMS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:75%">
            <span>JavaScript/jQuery</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
            <span>Photoshop</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Skills Progress Bar
$(function() {
  $('.progress-bar').each(function() {
      var bar_width = $(this).css('width'); // returns the css width value
      var bar_value = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
      console.log(bar_width);
      console.log(bar_value);
      $(this).animate({ value: bar_width }, { duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutCirc' });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the progress to be animated from zero to the amount specified in `aria-valuenow`. You are almost there!

1. Remove the `style` attribute from each of the progress bars as that will instantly put them at the final amount.
2. I've added `%` to the `bar_value` to make it be recognized as a percentage. Without a unit it will be seen as a pixel value.
3. The jQuery `animate` function needs to know which css property to animate. I've changed `value` in your code example into `width` to animate the `width` property
4. The `easeOutCirc` easing function exists only in jQuery UI. I'm not sure if you had that as a resource in your Bootply, but I've added it here.

```js
// Skills Progress Bar
$(function() {
  $('.progress-bar').each(function() {
    var bar_value = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow') + '%';                
    $(this).animate({ width: bar_value }, { duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutCirc' });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

/* Skills Progess Bar */

section#skills-pgr {
  padding: 3px 10px 0;
}
#skills-pgr div.progress {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 0px none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 2.5em;
}
div.progress-bar > span {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Skills Progress Bar -->
<section id="skills-pgr">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span>HTML/CSS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span>Photography</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span>CMS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span>JavaScript/jQuery</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span>Photoshop</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 3, it's very easy to animate progress bars. All you need to do, is change the width of your `.progress-bar`, like this :

```
$('.progress-bar').css('width', '80%');
```

Just repeat the process whenever your width value needs to be updated, until the process bar reaches 100%.

---

#### A demo

```js
var $progress = $('.progress');
var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
var $alert = $('.alert');

setTimeout(function() {
    $progressBar.css('width', '10%');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $progressBar.css('width', '30%');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $progress.css('display', 'none');
                $alert.css('display', 'block');
            }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
        }, 2000); // WAIT 2 seconds
    }, 1000); // WAIT 1 seconds
}, 1000); // WAIT 1 second
```

```css
.progress, .alert {
    margin: 15px;
}

.alert {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Loading completed!</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLgv2Lfm/8/))

Answer (score 1):

You could use setInterval timer and increase the width at some interval until it reaches a max width..

```
$('.progress-bar').each(function() {
    var $bar = $(this);
    var progress = setInterval(function() {

      var currWidth = parseInt($bar.attr('aria-valuenow'));
      var maxWidth = parseInt($bar.attr('aria-valuemax'));

      //update the progress
        $bar.width(currWidth+'%');
        $bar.attr('aria-valuenow',currWidth+10);

      //clear timer when max is reach
      if (currWidth >= maxWidth){
        clearInterval(progress);
      }

    }, 500);
});
```

http://bootply.com/tC8sgQRwDD#

Comment: This is not bad, but the animation isn't as smooth as I would like using the `animate` property.